# Finding which quadrant $\theta$ lies in given the value of only $\tan^{-1} \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

An author does the math as follows:
$$\theta  = \tan^{-1 } \frac{y}{x}$$
Here x and y are given arbitrary values of $\frac{-1}{2}$ and  $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ respectively. Putting the values we get:
$$\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}}{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

$$\theta = \tan^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}\  )\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$ 
After this the author says that $\theta\\$ belongs to the second quadrant, and writes:
$$\theta = \tan^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}\  ) = \frac{2\pi}{3}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
Which doesn't make  sense to me, since it gives $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ on the calculator.

Something I do understand is that from \eqref{eq1} I can deduce that:
$$\tan\ \theta = -\sqrt{3}$$
And since the value of $\tan$ is negative, then it can't be in the first and third quadrants, and it must be within the second or fourth one.

$\mathbf{Question\ 1}$: How do we find out which quadrant $\theta$ lies in?

$\mathbf{Question\ 2}$: How did the author equate $\theta$ in \eqref{eq2}?

Comment: $\arctan x$ is defined to be the angle in the range $\left(-\frac{\pi}2; \frac{\pi}2\right)$ whose tangent is $x$

Comment: If $\theta = tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3})$ then  $tan \theta = -60°$

Comment: You can deduce the quadrant from the given values of $x$ and $y$.  When you evaluate the tangent, you lose information since there are infinitely many values of $\theta$ with the same tangent since the tangent function has period $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

- $x<0$ and $y>0$

therefore we are in the second quadrant, for that reason, since the range for $\tan^{-1}x$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, we have that

$$\theta= \pi+\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}}{\frac{-1}{2}}\right)=\pi+\tan^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}) =\pi-\frac \pi 3=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Refer also to [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) for more details.

Comment: Why is $\pi$ being added to $\tan^{-1}\ (x)$ here? If the angle lies in the second quadrant, then should it not be represented by $\frac {\pi}{2} + \tan^{-1}\ (x)$ to show it's angle from the positive x axis?

Comment: @Arkilo The question is very simple! The inverse function $\arctan$ has range $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ therefore it gives the correct angle only when $x>0$. When $x<0$ we need to add $\pi$ in order to have the correct angle. When $x=0$ we only need to look $y$ to find $\theta$. Let make a sketch for the unitary circle to see that. Also refer to the link I've given. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Yeah I'm completely lost when it comes to finding the angle, I got 0 clues. What are we even talking about here? The co terminal angles? How am I suppose to navigate with just $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{-3}$ and knowing that it is in the third quadrant? Like what angle is it making with anything? If it said that it makes some angle say $\phi$ with the negative x axis or negative y axis, then I would have something to work with. Basically I don't know what I don't know

Comment: @Arkilo We can say that $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{-3}$ is in the second or in the fourth quadrant, indeed $\tan \theta$ is negative in this case. We know we are dealing with an angle in the second quadrant because $x<0$ and $y>0$ we need all these information to know which quadrant we are dealing with.

Comment: @Arkilo By the definition, $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{-3}$ returns a value in teh fourth quadrant and for that reason we need to add $\pi$ in such way we can recover the correct value in the second quadrant.

Comment: I understand why we choose the second quadrant, I don't follow the business with the values of $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{-3}$ , and that it has a "correct" value and recovering it. Would u have any references that I can read regarding this part to clear my understanding?

Comment: Ok nvm the Wikipedia article u mentioned above addresses this.

Comment: @Arkilo Well done! Let me know is something else is unclear.

Comment: Yes I have one final question, the function arctan produces a negative value which can be plotted perfectly nicely on a cartesian coordinate system, it just comes in the third quadrant(https://imgur.com/X6vmYW7), but seemingly it doesn't work so well in polar coordinates, because it outputs negative -60 degress which is impossible, but adding $\pi$ makes sense. My question is that will plotting softwares also have modules in their algorithms to deal with this when they are plotting in polar coordinates?

Comment: @Arkilo By definition $\arctan x$ has range in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and (usually) calculators returns the value in this range. On wolframaplha we can use the function $atan(x,y)$ which acts as the $atan2$ function I've linked earlier. See the example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28-1%2C1%29). Yes  of course good plotting softwares have modules in their algorithms to deal with this when they are plotting in polar coordinates

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you were very articulate and helpful. I didn't know this annoying problem would have such a satisfying explanation. Very cool stuff

Comment: @Arkilo You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Since your $x$ is negative and your $y$ is positvie you are in the second quadrant.

The angle is obvioully $\frac {2\pi}{3}$ and it is not  $\tan ^{-1} (-\sqrt{3})$

The calculator is correct because the $\arctan (x) $ is betweem $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$

The correct answer is $$\theta = \pi + \tan^{-1}(-\sqrt 3)$$